# Supabase with NextJS: how to prevent reload when the website blurs and returns on focu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase

I have the following structure in `_app.js` of the Next.js app

```
// _app.js
//
import ...
import { createBrowserSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { SessionContextProvider } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'

// below is the structure of the app 
// with a Data Provider that accesses the supabase db

import { DataProvider } from 'contexts/DataContext'
..
...
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  ...
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() => createBrowserSupabaseClient())
  ...
  return (
      <Layout>
        <SessionContextProvider
            supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
            initialSession={pageProps.initialSession} >
            
          <DataProvider>
            ....
          </DataProvider>
          ...
          ...
        </SessionContextProvider>
     </Layout>
  )
}
```

The following is the DataContext.js

```
// DataContext.js
//
import ...
import { useSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
import { useUser } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
...

const DataContext = createContext()

export function DataProvider({ children }) {
  ...
  // get supabase and user
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient()
  const user = useUser()
  ...
  // other values and functions passed on to children
  const val1 = ...
  const fun1 = ..

  // This useEffect gets called everytime the page returns to focus 
  useEffect(()=> {
     
     if(user) {  
        //do some loading
     }

  }, [user])
   return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{user, val1, func1}}>
       {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  }
}
```

I notice that everytime I move to some other tab on my browser and return to the app, the `useEffect` gets called. This in turn triggers a reload of data as per my logic.

How would be prevent a trigger of the useEffect caused by reloading of the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
It sounds like the issue you're experiencing may be related to how the browser handles the page's focus state. One approach to consider would be to add an event listener to detect when the page loses and gains focus, and then update the internal state accordingly. This way, you can prevent the useEffect from being triggered when the page refocuses, but still execute the logic when the user's state actually changes. Another possibility could be to look into the use of useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect, as it runs synchronously after the browser has painted the updates to the screen, rather than asynchronously like useEffect does.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Liabel. In fact, I am using internal states similar to what you were suggesting. The question is more about **WHY** is the useEffect change in user being called when I refocus. Since the user has not changed. I was hoping a way to avoid that being triggered all together.

Comment: Apologies. I wanted to add my response as a comment but it was sligthly too long, so I edited the answer instead